# what is the use of ori in this part of MIPS code?

Tags: assembly, mips

Can someone explain the use of "ori" here? I know it's bitwise OR, but I don't know how it works or why it's needed here.

```
 #objective of the program is to add 5 and 7
.data #variable declaration follow this line
.text #instructions follow this line
main:
ori $s0, $zero, 0x5
ori $s1, $zero, 0x7
add $t0, $s0, $s1
li $v0,10 # required for only QtSPIM
syscall # required for only QtSPIM
#end of program
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
  ori $s0, $zero, 0x5
  ori $s1, $zero, 0x7
```

The two instructions load a constant of 0x05 into register $s0 and 0x07 into register $s1.

MIPS doesn't has an instruction that directly loads a constant into a register. Therefore logical OR with a operand of zero and the immediate value is is used as a replacement. It has the same effect as move. Translated to c-style code these two lines are:

```
  $s0 = 0 | 0x05;
  $s1 = 0 | 0x07;
```

You could also use:

```
  addi $s0, $zero, 0x5
  addi $s1, $zero, 0x7
```

This does the same thing, but uses add instead of logical or. Translated to code this would be.

```
  $s0 = 0 + 0x05;
  $s1 = 0 + 0x07;
```

Comment: why can't we use li $s0, 5 instead?

Comment: LI is a pseudo instruction which gets translated into a LUI and ORI instruction pair. It is suitable if you want to load a 32 bit constant. For constants that fit into 16 bit the ORI way saves an instruction because LUI is not needed in this case. That's why you see ORI instead of LI here.

Comment: However, `LI` is nevertheless usable, because the assembler is clever enough to omit the `LUI` if not needed. Also note that `LI` may be translated to something other than `ORI`, such as `ADDIU`.